# Write and read from a stream asynchronously

Tags: c#, stream

I am wanting to write to and read from a stream asynchronously. I am using GCP's storage API, specifically `StorageClient.DownloadObjectAsync`. It takes a stream which gets written to. I want to pass the bytes that get written to that stream to another API I am calling as they are written.

What I am struggling with is the reading since it seems streams (`MemoryStream` in this case) does not support simultaneous reading and writing. Is there another option for this?

Here are the pertinent snippets:

Downloader

```
using (StorageClient sc = StorageClient.Create(cred))
{
    await sc.DownloadObjectAsync(
        "841f1487-d1b3-434d-8848-8a4bb0749b20",
        @"filename",
        stream);
}
```

Writer

```
// Use a BinaryReader?
using BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
int current = 0;
int total = 0;
do
{
    current = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (current > 0)
    {
        fileStore.WriteFile(out int numberOfBytesWritten, directoryHandle, total, buffer);
        total += current;
    }
} while (current > 0)
```

Edit - adding additional info

When I try to read while the file is downloading, I only get 1% of the bytes before the BinaryReader stops reading even though the file is fully in memory (and while this file can fit in memory, not all files will be able to).

Comment: How is this code being run? How do you know the stream doesn't support simultaneous read and write, what happens? The more details you can give us, the easier it is for us to see where it went wrong

Comment: The plan was two have two threads, one for writing and one for reading. When I try to read while the file is downloading, I only get 1% of the bytes before the BinaryReader stops reading even though the file is fully in memory (and while this file can fit in memory, not all files will be able to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another option for this?

The code is currently downloading to a memory stream and then writing it out to disk. If that's all you need to do with it, then passing a file stream instead of a memory stream should be sufficient.

> What I am struggling with is the reading since it seems streams (MemoryStream in this case) does not support simultaneous reading and writing.

This is correct. No built-in stream types support simultaneous reads and writes. One reason is that there's a notion of a single "position" that is updated by both reads and writes.

It should be *possible* to write a concurrent stream type. You'd need to handle concurrent access as well as having two positions rather than one, and some operations might not be supported for concurrent streams. I've thought about writing a type like this a few times, but didn't feel it was sufficiently useful in a world where [Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines), [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/), [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), and [async streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams) already exist.

So, I'd say:

1. If possible, just pass it a file stream and get rid of the memory stream completely.
2. Otherwise, explore the GCP API and see if there's a non-stream-based solution you can use to download.
3. If the GCP API *must* download to a stream *and* your code *must* do in-memory processing during the save, then you'll need to write a concurrent stream type.

Comment: 1. It's, unfortunately, not possible to use a FileStream. The reason is the application is running on Linux and the destination is an SMB share and FileStream does not support that scenario.
2. I've done some looking but got very much caught up on this implementation. I'll do some more digging.
3. Thought we would have to go this route but wanted to see if I was missing anything since I could not find anything on this.

Thanks!

Comment: On further thought, I think what you'd really want for a concurrent stream is to have *two* streams - one read-only and one write-only. The stream pair would be connected behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm not sure if .NET supports this on Linux, but anonymous named pipes essentially do the same thing: two streams that are connected. That may be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found what I wanted. The answer is using the `Pipe` class.

It was as simple as creating a new pipe (`Pipe pipe = new Pipe()`), modifying the downloader to take a `PipeWriter` instead of just a stream so that I can call `pw.CompleteAsync()` when I'm done writing (you can still get the stream with `pw.AsStream()`), and passing in the `PipeReader` stream with `pipe.Reader.AsStream()`.